# How to rename <ArrayOf> XML attribute that generated after serializing List of objects

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I am serializing List of objects  `List<TestObject>`
, and XmlSerializer generates `<ArrayOfTestObject>` attribute, I want rename it or remove it.
Can it be done with creating new class that encapsulated List as field?

```
 [XmlRoot("Container")]    
 public class TestObject
 {
     public TestObject() { }                         
     public string Str { get; set; }                         
 }

 List<TestObject> tmpList = new List<TestObject>();

 TestObject TestObj = new TestObject();
 TestObj.Str = "Test";

 TestObject TestObj2 = new TestObject();
 TestObj2.Str = "xcvxc";

 tmpList.Add(TestObj);
 tmpList.Add(TestObj2);


 XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
 settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
 settings.Indent = true;
 XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<TestObject>));

 using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(@"C:\test.xml", settings))
 {              
     XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
     namespaces.Add(string.Empty, string.Empty);
     serializer.Serialize(writer, tmpList, namespaces);                            
}


<ArrayOfTestObject>
  <TestObject>
    <Str>Test</Str>
  </TestObject>
  <TestObject>
    <Str>xcvxc</Str>
  </TestObject>
</ArrayOfTestObject>
```

Answer (score 33):

The most reliable way is to declare an outermost DTO class:

```
[XmlRoot("myOuterElement")]
public class MyOuterMessage {
    [XmlElement("item")]
    public List<TestObject> Items {get;set;}
}
```

and serialize *that* (i.e. put your list into another object).

---

You *can* avoid a wrapper class, but I wouldn't:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Foo>),
             new XmlRootAttribute("Flibble"));
        List<Foo> foos = new List<Foo> {
            new Foo {Bar = "abc"},
            new Foo {Bar = "def"}
        };
        ser.Serialize(Console.Out, foos);
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

The *problem* with this is that when you use custom attributes you need to be *very* careful to store and re-use the serializer, otherwise you get *lots* of dynamic assemblies loaded into memory. This is avoided if you just use the `XmlSerializer(Type)` constructor, as it caches this internally automatically.

Comment: Marc hit the nail on the head.  I did a similar trick over at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3000934/return-xml-data-from-a-web-service/3001176#3001176

Comment: So there is no way to avoid using another class?

Comment: There is a better and easier way, just se this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237683/xml-serialization-of-listt-xml-root

Comment: @Fedearne which better/easier way is that? do you mean the accepted answer which is *identical* to the second suggestion above? And note very carefully the reasoning I gave as to why this is dangerous.

Comment: @Marc Gravell do I need to create a separate MyOuterMessage for each type I'm serializing?

Comment: @MarcGravell I ask a similar question, would you please check it, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13247449/customize-xml-serialize-with-new-tags-and-attributes-and-root

Comment: @Saeid sorry, but that's a very different question; I don't mess around with soap envelopes much

Answer (score 11):

Change the following line from:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<TestObject>));
```

To:

```
XmlRootAttribute root = new XmlRootAttribute("TestObjects");     

XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<TestObject>), root);
```

It should work.

Comment: Down voted.  This method will insert a root element but it still won't remove the "ArrayOfTestObject" element.

Answer (score 5):

You can add an additional parameter to the `XmlSerializer` constructor to essentially name the root element.

```
XmlSerializer xsSubmit = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<DropDownOption>), new XmlRootAttribute("DropDownOptions"));
```

This would result in the following structure:

```
<DropDownOptions xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"> 
    <DropDownOption>
      <ID>1</ID>
      <Description>foo</Description>
    </DropDownOption>
    <DropDownOption>
      <ID>2</ID>
      <Description>bar</Description>
    </DropDownOption>
</DropDownOptions>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create another class like :

```
       [XmlRoot("TestObjects")]
       public class TestObjects: List<TestObject>
       {

       }
```

Then apply below code while sealizing :

```
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TestObjects));
            MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
            serializer.Serialize(memStream, tmpList);
```

Comment: This didn't have any effect in my case. I _guess_ the built-in serializer just looks if the object to serialize is a child of `List` in order to apply its special naming scheme.