# Serialize list with a certain format

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to rename <ArrayOf> XML attribute that generated after serializing List of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3129001/how-to-rename-arrayof-xml-attribute-that-generated-after-serializing-list-of-o)

This should be really simple but I am missing something here. I need output xml in the below format when serializing my class.

```
<items>
 <item id="1" name="John">
 <item id="2" name="Peter">
 <item id="3" name="Shane">
<items>
```

Here is the class:

```
public class Item
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string Id;
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string Name;
    }
```

Here is my test code:

```
var items = new List<Item>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                var item = new Item();
                item.Id = i.ToString();
                item.Name = "Jeff" + " - " + i.ToString();
                items.Add(item);
            }
            Ser(items);

static void Ser(object o)
        {
            XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(o.GetType());

            var xns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            xns.Add(string.Empty, string.Empty);

            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;
            settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
            XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(Console.Out, settings);

            x.Serialize(writer, o, xns);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

Output I am getting is:

```
<ArrayOfItem>
  <Item Id="0" Name="Jeff - 0" />
  <Item Id="1" Name="Jeff - 1" />
  <Item Id="2" Name="Jeff - 2" />
  <Item Id="3" Name="Jeff - 3" />
</ArrayOfItem>
```

I want to replace "ArrayOfItem" with "Items". Also, why am I seeing "ArrayOf" appended? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use **linq2Xml**..It is simple and cool

```
XElement doc=new XElement("Items");

foreach(var item in items)
{
    doc.Add(
        new XElement("Item",
        new XAttribute("Id",item.Id),new XAttribute("Name",item.Name)
           )
    );
}

doc.ToString();//your xml
```

**Output**:

```
<items>
 <item id="1" name="John">
 <item id="2" name="Peter">
 <item id="3" name="Shane">
<items>
```

Comment: I wanted to create xml on the fly and this works well for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `ArrayOfItem` as you are getting type of `List<Item>` which is `Array` of type `Item`. This is standard when you de-serialize the xml de-serializer will make array of type `Item`. You can serialize individual `Item` for format like that but still it won't be same.

If you serialize individual item you'll get

```
  <Item Id="0" Name="Jeff - 0" />
  <Item Id="1" Name="Jeff - 1" />
  <Item Id="2" Name="Jeff - 2" />
  <Item Id="3" Name="Jeff - 3" />
```