# How can return an xml file for a web service method in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asmx

I would like to return a XML file as output of a web service method in asp.net.Can anyone help with an example.

This is the web service method i have done.But when i call the "Hai" method ,I am getting an error.The error i got is given below:

**There is an error in XML Document(1,287)**.

```
[WebMethod]
public XElement hai()
{
    try
    {


        XElement xmlTree1 = new XElement("Root",
                            new XElement("Child1", 1),
                            new XElement("Child2", 2),
                            new XElement("Child3", 3),
                            new XElement("Child4", 4),
                            new XElement("Child5", 5),
                            new XElement("Child6", 6)
        );

        return xmlTree1;
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can see following link.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3000934/return-xml-data-from-a-web-service

Comment: FYI, are you aware that ASMX should not be used for new development?

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, you can return an `XmlDocument` :

```
[WebMethod]
public XmlDocument hai()
{
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

        XmlNode rootNode = doc.CreateElement("products");
        doc.AppendChild(rootNode);

        XmlNode product1Node = doc.CreateElement("product");
        rootNode.AppendChild(product1Node);

        XmlNode product1NameNode = doc.CreateElement("Name");
        product1NameNode.InnerText = "Product 1";
        product1Node.AppendChild(product1NameNode);
        XmlNode product1ColorNode = doc.CreateElement("Color");
        product1ColorNode.InnerText = "Blue";
        product1Node.AppendChild(product1ColorNode);

        XmlNode product2Node = doc.CreateElement("product");
        rootNode.AppendChild(product2Node);

        XmlNode product2NameNode = doc.CreateElement("Name");
        product2NameNode.InnerText = "Product 2";
        product2Node.AppendChild(product2NameNode);
        XmlNode product2ColorNode = doc.CreateElement("Color");
        product2ColorNode.InnerText = "Yellow";
        product2Node.AppendChild(product2ColorNode);

        return doc;
}
```

**Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<products>
    <product>
        <Name>Product 1</Name>
        <Color>Blue</Color>
    </product>
    <product>
        <Name>Product 2</Name>
        <Color>Yellow</Color>
    </product>
</products>
```

Comment: How would it help the OP to use a different XML technology?

Comment: The OP wants to return an XML from a webservice no matter the XML technology as he doesn't specify it.

Comment: The OP is already using XElement. How would XmlElement be better?

Comment: I never said that XmlDocument is better than XElement I just said that it is an alternative way to do it. Your answer is even worse, OP wants to generate XML (He tried to achieve it in his example code + mentioned it in comments below your answer) and return it. Your code just loads a file and return it. And you're the one downvoting my answer? Seriously?

Comment: I reviewed the edit history. My answer came before the OP had any detail in the question. It only said "how do I return an XML file". Two days later, the OP added code showing what he was trying to do (and how he was trying to call the service). It seems like I did not notice that edit. That edit shows (slightly) what error the OP received, but neither of our answers address the error. That's why I just deleted my answer.

Comment: I still don't see how you help the OP by simply showing that there's an alternative way to do the same thing he's already doing. That's especially true since your way uses an older technology which is not nearly as easy to use. Especially after all this time, with no reason to believe the OP is looking for alternate XML technologies, I am _still_ standing by my downvote.